# multiple user, single website analytics

Tags: php, html, analytics

I am developing a web application which will have multiple users. It's basically an eCommerce system where multiple vendors sell their products

Now I need to use Analytics to track how customers come, and how is their flow.

I need to give different account (i.e., analytics account) to each vendor. Vendor can have that tracking code on their website as well, so that they can track customers that are coming from their website (something like funnel)

For example:

> Customer lands on vendor site -> looks for a specific product -> find product page -> click on view more details button -> lands on eCommerce application -> view details of product -> decides to buy

Now, vendor will place tracking code on their website, or webpage. Same code will be appended on eCommerce application.

I need to know whether any such Analytics plugin / application is available or not?

Thanks

Comment: @experimentX: Google analytics is a good option, but I want to host analytics on my own domain i.e., control should be with me.

Comment: like who' my referrer (google search or google ads or yahoo or  .. my own ads ..)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have access to the web server, you can employ log file analysis on each site's log separately then create accounts for your clients to view the statistics for their respective stores. This would involve installing something like AWStats, http://awstats.sourceforge.net/,  on your server, creating accounts for each of your customers, and creating a script to parse the access logs on a regular basis.

You could also go with something like Piwik, http://piwik.org/,  and install it on your server. Once installed, create the accounts and attach the necessary scripts to the stores, then give your customers the account information so they can perform their own site analyses at their own leisure.